# Error:Module 'App name': platform 'android-15' not found

Tags: android-studio, google-gdk

I am trying to start a project for google glass in android studio. I have all the SDK platforms required but still android studio keeps on giving me this error. Does anyone have any clue whats going on?

[image: Everything is installed!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooooo...... remember to make changes in your `build.gradle`

change `compileSdkVersion` 15 to compileSdkVersion `"Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek:15"`

Answer (score 1):

I just selected the **update SDK** option and then did rebuild. It said **daemon started successfully**

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `compileSdkVersion` to a lower one, synced, that failed, changed it back to the previous value, synced and it properly built. Very arbitrary, I know.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. If you're on a mac than go into Android Studio/preferences/Appearance & Behavior/Android SDK and click on the SDK Tools tab. Update the Android SDK Platform Tools.

After you've updated this in the preference, go to Build/Clean Project. This takes a few seconds. When complete, go to Build/Rebuild Project.

The build should be successful this time.

**If this doesn't work then go into file/ invalidate cashes restart**

Hope this helps, Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Change `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to the most current versions.