# Google Glass Android Studio Gradle issues

Tags: android, android-studio, google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to build my first Google Glass app, using Android Studio 0.5.4. But am getting a build error: `Error:Module 'TestApplication-TestApplication': platform 'Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek:15' not found.`

[image]

As you can see the GDK, and all necessary library files are installed.

[image: libs]

I have looked at a few different questions about this already, primarily

- [Google Glass: GDK with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107002/google-glass-gdk-with-android-studio)
- [Android Studio || GDK 'hello word' || import com.google.android.glass.app.Card || Cannot Resolve Symbol 'google'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695542/android-studio-gdk-hello-word-import-com-google-android-glass-app-card)
- [Error:Module 'App name': platform 'android-15' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725158/errormodule-app-name-platform-android-15-not-found)

Which recommends to change `compileSdkVersion` in the `build.gradle` to this

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek:15"
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is likely a bug in Android Studio. I'm experiencing the same thing as of updating to 0.5.4, and gradle is able to build fine when called from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be resolved in Android Studio 0.5.5, so if you update via "Help->Check for Update..." it should work.

A workaround, if you still have problems:

1. Open up the "Terminal" window
2. Run `gradlew installDebug` each time you want to install the app (press "up" to recall the last command)

[image]

I had this issue with Android Studio 0.5.4, but on only one of two machines.

I started a [Glass app](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/onebusaway-android/tree/glass) in Android Studio on one machine and Android Studio built the app without any problems, and when I cloned the exact same project from Github on another machine Android Studio gave me the same error you're seeing - `Error:Module 'onebusaway-android': platform 'Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek:15' not found.`  But, gradle from the command line still works fine.